# Java packing a module with a automatic module into a JAR

Tags: java, jar, modularity, java-platform-module-system

I'm playing around with modules but there is something that I cannot perform so far is fact is quite simple but is not working.

I have a module named Student with only 1 package which exports and requires a class in a non-modular jar is something like this.

[image: ModuleSourcePath]

The relevant code here is that Administracion class requires a class in a non-modular jar the code is like this.

```
public class Administracion extends classpath.ClassPathClass{
```

In this example I am considering that I don't have the sources only the binaries in a Jar file in fact the jar is located on the root of next to src but in out directory

Like this:

[image: Jar file in the out directory]

I can compile all the module code with this command

```
C:\Ocp11>javac -d out --module-source-path src -p out --module Student
```

Great, the binaries are located in the out directory and now it looks like this:

[image: out directory]

I can run it with this command:

```
C:\Ocp11>java -p out --module Student/university.upel.Administracion
```

And runs like a charm but the step I could not perform I package it.

I would like to ignore the module root folder I mean the Student is this possible for be able to run the main class easier.

I would like to have a structure in the jar like this.

[image: I would like to have this layout]

I have tried this:

```
C:\Ocp11>jar --create --file App.jar -e university.upel.Administracion -C out/Student .
```

This is creating the JAR and if I unzip it I see what I wanted.

```
The Jar file ClassPath.jar
The module-info.class for creating this as a module
The Main-Class: university.upel.Administracion
```

Package structure:

[image: File Structure on the unziped Jar file]

In fact if I see the module-info.class using Javap I see this

```
C:\Ocp11>javap App/module-info.class
Compiled from "module-info.java"
module Student {
  requires java.base;
  requires ClassPath;
  exports university.upel;
}
```

At this time I'm thinking well seems to work. The run:

```
C:\Ocp11>java -p App.jar -m Student
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module ClassPath not found, required by Student
```

It is saying that the module ClassPath the automatic module is not present even when the ClassPath.jar is inside the jar I think this is not possible right? I'm stuck at this moment.

I just thought that in this way the Student would be a module with a automatic module inside and that would locate the automatic module on each run.

I am sure I'm wrong or I am taking the wrong approach.

If I change the command a little bit locates the Jar and runs without a issue.

```
C:\Ocp11>java -p App.jar;out/ClassPath.jar -m Student
OUTPUT
```

So can I not put the JAR inside the JAR and run it? Is a kind annoying the carrying the 2 jars file even when only this jar uses the Automatic module.

Comment: There's no need to apologise for your English. Just use an English spell-checker on your written work to catch the wrongly spelled words, the grammar doesn't have to be perfect. Try to stick to technical writing if you can.